# How to correctly get the UUID of the entire disk?

Tags: disk, uuid

As UUID's are assigned in partitioning phase (by software), there is no UUID available for entire disk.

However, `/dev/disk/by-id/` contains promising information for the same purpose. We can get the "UUID" path for - eg. `/dev/sdb/` by:

```
$ disk=sdb; ls /dev/disk/by-id/ -l | grep "/$disk$" | awk '{print "/dev/disk/by-id/"$9}'
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST1000LM048-2E7172_WKP6XK95
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c500ccbb7485
```

However, as you can see, there are more than one entry for the same drive. The one ends with `WKP6XK95` makes more sense since it is physically written on the product tag, in "Serial Number" section.

How can I get the only value that is possibly written on the disk? In other words, how is the `wwn-...` id generated so how can I safely ignore this entry? Would ignoring this entry by `... | grep -v wwn` be safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wwn-` entry is the World Wide Name of the disk. It is technically not an UUID, because it does not follow the UUID format nor generation rules.

On stand-alone SATA and SAS disks, it is reported by the disk firmware and assigned at factory. On SAN storage systems it might be more complicated: as the storage is presented as LUNs (Logical UNits), the storage system assigns WWNs for them.

It's like a MAC address, but for disks: the idea is that you should practically never have the same WWN on two different pieces of storage (unless you play tricks with SAN storage virtualization hardware).

`lsscsi -UU` should also display the WWN, although prefixed with `naa.` instead of `wwn-0x`. `lsblk -o +WWN` can also display it.

In `/dev/disk/by-id/`, you should pay attention to the prefixes: you can find the disk WWN string prefixed with `wwn-0x` and/or `scsi-3`, depending on version of `udev` used by your distribution.

The concept of a whole-disk UUID assigned when the partition table is written exists for the GPT partitioning scheme. You can see it in e.g. `fdisk -l` output:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 850 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2B05CCE8-92BC-4308-B770-174CE63D044F   <--- Here!
```

Other partitioning schemes, like MBR, won't necessarily have anything applicable, and even if they have, it is not necessarily in the form of a valid UUID.

For MBR partitioning scheme, the closest equivalent is Windows Disk Signature (offset 0x1B8 in the actual MBR), but it's only four bytes long and not guaranteed to exist on all MBR-partitioned disks. I think it was introduced in Windows NT.

Answer (score 0):

I won't repeat what telcoM [has said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/559659/126755), just adding maybe useful one-liner.

---

#### My way to filter out all of my SATA drives + UUIDs

```
LC_ALL=C fdisk -l /dev/sd? | grep 'Disk /dev/sd\|Disk identifier'
```

---

#### Parsing

- `LC_ALL=C`: setting the base locale without exporting it, works just for this command
- `fdisk -l /dev/sd?`: list drive(s), in our case we're picky and doing only `/dev/sd?`
- `grep 'Disk /dev/sd\|Disk identifier'`: show only disk name + UUID